# IllegalArgumentException when trying to get objects from Oracle database with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, illegalargumentexception

This is my method which talks to the database with JPA:

```
public Collection<ModuleConnection> getConnections(int parentModuleId) {
  Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT moduleConnection FROM ModuleConnection As moduleConnection WHERE moduleConnection.parentModule = :parentModuleId");
  query.setParameter("parentModuleId", parentModuleId);
  List<ModuleConnection> cons = query.getResultList();
  return cons;
}
```

I am calling this method like this:

```
Collection<ModuleConnection> connections = bh.getConnections(module.getModuleId());
```

Everytime I do this, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field xyz.BomModule.moduleId to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3619)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
    at xyz.getConnections(BomHandling.java:194)
    at org.apache.jsp.js.jquery_002dtreeview.demo.bom_005fexample_jsp._jspService(bom_005fexample_jsp.java:222)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
11:38:03,373 ERROR [CachedConnectionValve] Application error: jsp did not complete its transaction
```

This is how the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "MODULECONNECTION"
(
    "ID"                    NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "QUANTITY"              NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PARENTMODULE_MODULEID" NUMBER(10,0),
    "SUBMODULE_MODULEID"    NUMBER(10,0)
)
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I seem to recall this being a problem with autoboxing, try changing `getConnections(int parentModuleId)` to `getConnections(Integer parentModuleId)`

Comment: It doesn't change anything, same error.

Comment: Hrm, perhaps try `query.setParameter("parentModuleId", new Integer(parentModuleId));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query should just be

```
SELECT moduleConnection FROM ModuleConnection As moduleConnection 
WHERE moduleConnection.parentModule.id = :parentModuleId
```

You could use your original query if the argument of the query was of type Module (the type of the associated entity, and not the type of its ID)

Comment: This is not the same query as the one I told you to use. Show us the code og your entities.

Comment: No it's not. Where is the parentModule path?

Comment: Sorry for this. I actually had two methods, and did not recognize that the error has been thrown by the other method. You were right, changing it to `parentModule.id` did indeed fix it. Thanks a lot for this.